# Shelltreeview getting path from node

Tags: delphi

I am using a custom hint with onMouseMove and it is working properly the problem I am having is returning the full path to a string, here is what I have for code.

```
procedure TCoreVMain.CoreShellTreeViewMouseMove(Sender: TObject;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);

  var
   tree: TsShellTreeView;
   hoverNode: TTreeNode;
   hitTest : THitTests;

begin

 if (Sender is TsShellTreeView) then
     tree := TsShellTreeView(Sender)
   else
     Exit;

   hoverNode := tree.GetNodeAt(X, Y) ;
   hitTest := tree.GetHitTestInfoAt(X, Y) ;
 if (lastHintNode <> hoverNode) then
   begin
     Application.CancelHint;

     if (hitTest <= [htOnItem, htOnIcon, htOnLabel, htOnStateIcon]) then
     begin
       lastHintNode := hoverNode;
       FileToolPanel.Caption := tree.path; //hovernode.Text;
       tree.Hint := NodeHint(hoverNode) ;
     end;
   end;
end;
```

The hovernode.text returns only the display name "temp" instead of "c:\temp", how can I recover the full path of a node when the node item is hovered over and not selected?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert from the node to its associated shell folder. Which you can do like this:

```
var 
  shellFolder: TShellFolder;
....
shellFolder := tree.Folders[hoverNode.Index];
```

The shell folder object is just stored in the node's `Data` property so you can do it like this:

```
shellFolder := TShellFolder(hoverNode.Data);
```

Once you have the shell folder you can get the full path with

```
tree.Hint := shellFolder.PathName;
```

Comment: +1 which could be shortened to  tree.Hint := TShellFolder(tv.Selected.Data).PathName;

Comment: @Bummi Not quite because the hover node is not the same as the selected node.